# Highcharts plot gives an x-axis which is twice the length of my datasets

Tags: python, highcharts, flask

[image]
I am using Flask to plot data with Highcharts. I cannot work out why I often get plots where the x-axis has twice the number of time points as it should (see the chart on the left). This only seems to happen where there is missing data (e.g. with the PM2.5 series). Here is the code I am using:

```
hours = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%H:%M'), 
        ([d['@MeasurementDateGMT'] for d in array[0:24])))
pm10 = [d['@Value'] if d['@Value'] == '' else float(d['@Value']) for d in array if d['@SpeciesCode'] == 'PM10']
pm25 = [d['@Value'] if d['@Value'] == '' else float(d['@Value']) for d in array if d['@SpeciesCode'] == 'FINE']
no2 = [d['@Value'] if d['@Value'] == '' else float(d['@Value']) for d in array if d['@SpeciesCode'] == 'NO2']
chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height, }
series = [{"name": 'PM10', "data": pm10}, {"name": 'PM2.5', "data": pm25},
          {"name": 'Nitrogen Dioxide', "data": no2}]
title = {"text": 'My Title'}
xAxis = {"categories": hours}
yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'Concentration (ug/m3'}}
return render_template('detail.html', chartID=chartID, chart=chart, series=series, title=title, xAxis=xAxis,
                       yAxis=yAxis)
```

The 'hours' variable is a list of hours from 00:00 to 23:00, and pm10, pm25 and no2 are lists of float values, with an empty string for missing data. The lists all have a length of 24 values, which is why I don't understand why there are 48 points on the x-axis.

```
hours = ['01:00', '02:00', '03:00'....23:00]
pm10 = [24.8, 21.2, '', 21.5, 9.3,.....21.8]
```

Can anyone see why this is happening and what changes to the code I need to make?

Comment: You can set max manually for the axis - xAxis.max = 23. See the API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max

Comment: I think you'll have to dig into the chart object. I would check **1)** the data, as it appears in the chart object - something is likely in the data that is extending the axis - or **2)** the `xAxis`, and look for the extremes, and anything that might be out of place there. Post your series data object, and your x axis object here if you can't find a problem. If it's always going to be 0-23, setting the max manually is a good option, but still good idea to work out where the error is coming from.